# AS3/JavaScript if statement commas instead of & &

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, if-statement, boolean-logic, comma-operator

This runs in ActionScript 3 and JavaScript. Why? I know how `&&` and `||` work, but a list? Is this AS3 specific? Is this in other languages? I'm a mouth breathing PHP/AS2 programmer. Or did everyone already know this and I'm a tool for not reading documentation properly?

AS3

```
if (true, true, true) {
     trace("true?")
}
//result - "true?" traced
```

JavaScript

```
if (true, true, true) {
    alert("true?");
}
//result - "true?" alert message popped up

if (false, false, false) {
    alert("true?");
}
else {
    alert("false");
}
//result - "false" alert message popped up

if(true, false, false) {
    alert("true?");
}
else {
    alert("false");
}
//result - "false" alert message popped up
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a comma do in JavaScript expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561043/what-does-a-comma-do-in-javascript-expressions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume JavaScript has a comma operator like C, which takes multiple arguments and returns the last one. It's typically used to for loops where you want to initialize more than one value:

```
for(i=0, j=0; j< 10; j++) {  
...   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The comma is used to evaluate expressions in a sequence, the same thing could be done with parenthesis groups separated by &&

Comment: I think this is wrong. Evealuating in a sequence can either return the value of the first expression, the value of the last expression, all values ORed together or ANDed together. I think it returns the last expression as the first answers says.