# Warning JSHint with backbone : Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jshint

On all my JS files, i have a warning of JSHint : Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

A example :

```
/*global App, Backbone*/

App.Routers = App.Routers || {};

(function () {
    'use strict';

    App.Routers.ApplicationRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

        routes: {
            '': 'home',
            '!/case-projet/:projet(/)': 'projetService',
            '!/case-projet/:projet/Galerie(/)': 'galerieService',
            '!/case-projet(/)': 'homeEvents',
        },
        projetService: function (e) {
            this.loadView(e), App.activeProjectView.enterFromRouter();
        },
        galerieService: function (e) {
            this.loadView(e), App.activeProjectView.enterGalleryFromRouter();
        },
        homeEvents: function (e) {
            this.loadView(e),
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('.line[data-id="events"]').offset().top}, 2000, 'easeInOutQuint');
        },
        home: function () {
            new App.Views.Homeview();
        },
        loadView: function (e) {
            switch (e) {
            case 'Homeview':
                App.loadView(new App.Views.Homeview());
                break;
            case 'Incentive':
                App.loadView(new App.Views.Incentive());
                break;
            case 'Corporate':
                App.loadView(new App.Views.Corporate());
                break;
            case 'Convention':
                App.loadView(new App.Views.Convention());
                break;
            case 'Studio':
                App.loadView(new App.Views.Studio());
                break;
            default:
                App.loadView(null);
            }
        }

    });

})();
```

on http://www.jshint.com/ i have :

Four warnings
17  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
20  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
24  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
27  Do not use 'new' for side effects

Thanks

Comment: Use a semicolon, you're abusing the comma operator.

Comment: What is the difference between semicolon and comma ? (technical)

Comment: @Dossp: ***Where*** are you getting the errors? This is a fairly fundamental thing to include in the question.

Comment: @Dossp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561043/what-does-a-comma-do

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: it's not an error per se, just a JSHint warning. The first three warnings are in `projetService`, `galerieService` and `homeEvents`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said *where* you're getting these errors, but for instance here you're using the comma operator for no good reason:

```
this.loadView(e), App.activeProjectView.enterFromRouter();
```

Just do:

```
this.loadView(e);
App.activeProjectView.enterFromRouter();
```

Re `new` with side effects, it's complaining about this:

```
new App.Views.Homeview();
```

There, `new` is being used to construct an object, but then you're not saving the object reference (the result of the `new` expression) anywhere. So it's only being used for side-effects (*other* things that happen in the function), which is not generally a good idea.