# Javascript: ternary operator inside "if" condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ternary-operator

I found this Javacript code and I am unable to understand what it means to have a ternary operator inside an if condition.

```
var s = 10, r = 0, c = 1, h = 1, o = 1;

if (s > r ? (c = 5, h = 2) : h = 1, o >= h)
{
  alert(1);
}
```

Is the `o >= h` the result being returned to evaluate in the "if" condition?
And what about the use of comma in "if" condition?

Comment: 1) yes; 2) assignment of 1 to `h`.

Comment: Please read about ternary operators in JS before posting. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: See [How to use the ?: (ternary) operator in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6259982/1529630) and [What does a comma do in JavaScript expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3561043/1529630)

Comment: Sorry, but I voted to close it as a duplicate (because it is explained really well in the two linked answers). If you have any specific question not covered by those ones, please explain it and we'll reopen it.

Comment: Why do people go out of their way to make code that's hard to understand? `h=2` doesn't make any sense in terms of an `if` statement.

Comment: @Andy All `s>r ? (c=5,h=2) : h=1` should be moved before the `if`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really just a syntaxic short-cut. One can expand this into two `if` statements:

```
var condition;
if (s > r) {
  c = 5;
  condition = (h = 2); // another short-cut; it's essentially (h = 2, condition = true)
}
else {
  h = 1;
  condition = (o >= h);
}

if (condition) {
  alert(1);
}
```

Using `comma` allows to turn two statements into a single one (as `a, b` always evaluates to `b`, though both `a` and `b` sub-expressions are evaluated in process).

Comment: A good question would be : which piece of code is the more readable ? Ternary operator shortcut or this one ?

Comment: Sure, but what do you think `h=2` is testing?

Comment: Nothing; it's always truthy. It's another short-cut to combine assigning `2` to `h` and setting `condition` to `true` in one statement.

Answer (score -1):

This code will not give error when u run ...  basically ...  what is does is run the ternary operation where it finds (c=5,h=2) which is not a condition to write in if statement ..
hence the condition wont satisfy and it wont alert(1);