# How can I emulate a 'break' or even a 'continue' inside a 'forEach' loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach, break, continue

Here is what I would like to do. However there's no "continue" inside a forEach.

```
    var que = null
    self.qs.forEach((q) => {
        if (q.synchronized == false) {
            que = q;
            break; // I would like to do this
        }
    });
    //  Now que would be set to the first not synchronized
```

Can anyone tell me how I can do this. Note that I am using the latest browsers. Please note I am only looking for **one** object in the array where synchronized == true. Sorry I used "continue" in my question earlier. The functionality I am looking for is "break".

Comment: why continue? just `break;` or you might use filter.

Comment: Sorry I should have used "break"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to short circuit Array.forEach like calling break?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `Array.prototype.some`:

short form:

```
self.qs.some((q) => {
   return (q.synchronized == false) && (que = q, true);
});
```

or:

```
self.qs.some((q) => {
   if (q.synchronized == false)
   {
      que = q;
      return true;
   }
});
```

or:

```
self.qs.some(q => (q.synchronized == false) && (que = q, true));
```

`Array.prototype.some` returns on the first result that returns true.

`Array.prototype.every` returns on the first result that returns false.

They are basically tests for:

- some: does at least 1 item return true
- every: does every item return true

You can abuse this for something you want here :-)

The 3rd example is a bit of JS-fu but generates a nice oneliner ^_^

full code:

```
var que;
self.qs.some((q) => {
   if (q.synchronized == false)
   {
      que = q;
      return true;
   }
});
if (que) {
   // handle que here
}
```

**Unoptimized dirty hack:**

You could also use reduce for this:

```
var que = self.qs.reduce((result, q) => {
    if (que != null) return result;
    return (q.synchronized == false) ? q : result;
}, null);
// js-fu version
var que = self.qs.reduce((result,q) => que || (q.synchronized == false ? q : que),null);
```

Very unoptimized, but it saves you defining a var... It has no early out though.

Comment: You mention "some: does at least 2 item return true".  However what I am looking for is something that will only return 1 item.

Comment: `some` returns true or false. that's why you set `que = q` in it :-) also: `at least 1`.

Comment: Can you explain (que = q, true).  I've never seen this before. Thanks

Comment: @Marilou It's the [comma operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561043/what-does-a-comma-do-in-javascript-expressions).

Answer (score 2):

The [MDN page on `forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) has this to say:

> Note: There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by throwing an exception. **If you need such behaviour, the .forEach() method is the wrong tool, use a plain loop instead**. If you are testing the array elements for a predicate and need a boolean return value, you can use every() or some() instead.

(my emphasis)

I think given your requirement of finding just the first entry, why not use just a plain loop:

```
var que = null
for (var i = 0; i < self.qs.length; i++)
{
    if (!self.qs[i].synchronized) {
        que = self.qs[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

Simple, straightforward and easy to understand exactly what's going on for future maintainers of the code.  Just because we have fancy functions like `forEach`, `some`, `reduce` etc doesn't mean you have to use them in every single situation.

Comment: but but... my shiny toys...! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.prototype.find();`:

```
que = self.qs.find((q, i) =>  q.synchronized === true);
```

> #### Description
>
> The find method executes the callback function once for each element present in the array until it finds one where callback returns a true value. ***If such an element is found, find immediately returns the value of that element.*** Otherwise, find returns undefined. callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values; it is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values.

```js
var self = {
    "qs": [{
      synchronized: false,
      a: "b"
    }, {
      synchronized: true,
      xyz: "abc"
    }, {
      synchronized: true,
      xyz: "abc"
    }, {
      synchronized: true,
      xyz: "abc"
    }]
  },
  que = self.qs.find(function(q, i, arr) {
    console.log(i);
    return q.synchronized === true
  });

document.write(JSON.stringify(que, 0, 4));
```

Comment: Sorry my question may not have been clear so I just changed it. I want to find only one (first one that is found) where synchronized == false. It's possible there could be many of these but I just want to get the first.

Comment: In your case you should have used `return;`

Comment: Even better - I didn't know about `find` :)

Comment: Even i didn't know about it, was exploring some other options.

Comment: Right - I see it's new in 6 - would explain not being able to use it here yet :)

Comment: you didn't hear about find because it's unsupported in like many of the browsers. It's pretty new :-)

Comment: As OP is using typescript, so no worries i guess that will transpile it down.

Comment: sharp! didn't see that :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP explicitly did ask for ***"emulate[ing] a `break` ... inside a `forEach` loop"***, and since the language core now has much more features than almost 8 years ago, one actually could implement quite easily a prototypal array method which not only enables a `break` but also a `continue` command, similar to both statements [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) and  [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue).

In order to achieve the implementation of the iterating array method, one first needs to write some abstractions which do borrow the basic idea from [`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/AbortController) and its related [`AbortSignal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal).

Thus, one would implement e.g. a `PausedStateSignal` ...

```
class PausedStateSignal extends EventTarget {
  // shared protected/private state.
  #state;

  constructor(connect) {
    super();

    this.#state = {
      isPaused: false,
    };
    connect(this, this.#state);
  }
  get paused() {
    return this.#state.isPaused;
  }
}
```

... which is going to be used by its `PauseController` ...

```
class PauseController {
  #signal;
  #signalState;

  constructor() {
    new PausedStateSignal((signal, signalState) => {

      this.#signal = signal;
      this.#signalState = signalState;
    });
    this.#signalState.isPaused = false;
  }
  get signal() {
    return this.#signal;
  }

  break() {
    const isPaused = this.#signalState.isPaused;

    if (!isPaused) {
      this.#signalState.isPaused = true;
    }
    this.#signal.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent('break', { detail: { pausedBefore: isPaused } })
    );
    return !isPaused;
  }
  continue() {
    const isPaused = this.#signalState.isPaused;

    if (isPaused) {
      this.#signalState.isPaused = false;
    }
    this.#signal.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent('continue', { detail: { pausedBefore: isPaused } })
    );
    return isPaused;
  }
}
```

... where `PausedStateSignal` has to extend [`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/EventTarget) in order to be able of signaling state-changes via [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent), and where `PauseController` features the two main methods `break` and `continue`.

Both implementations are relying on [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) syntax, [private properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_properties), [`get` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#using_getters_in_classes) and a private, protected `state` object which gets shared by reference in between a controller and a signal instance. The latter gets achieved by a `connect`ing callback function which is passed at a signal's instantiation time.

Having covered that part, one can continue with the actual implementation of an array method which, in addition of the standard `forEach` functionality, is capable of three things ...

- allowing to **pause/halt the callback function's execution** via `break`,
- and via `continue` allowing ...

  - either to **continue a paused/halted loop**,
  - or to **skip the loop's next iteration step**.

The implementation could be named e.g. `forEachAsyncBreakAndContinue`; it does make use of the above described signal and controller abstractions, might look like follows ...

```
function forEachAsyncBreakAndContinue(callback, context = null) {
  const { promise, reject, resolve } = Promise.withResolvers();

  const controller = new PauseController;
  const { signal } = controller;

  const arr = this;
  const { length } = arr;

  let idx = -1;

  function continueLooping() {
    while(++idx < length) {

      if (signal.paused) {
        --idx;

        break;
      }
      try {
        callback.call(context, arr.at(idx), idx, arr, controller);

      } catch (exception) {

        reject(exception.message ?? String(exception));
      }
    }
    if (idx >= length) {

      resolve({ success: true });
    }
  }
  signal.addEventListener('continue', ({ detail: { pausedBefore } }) => {
    if (pausedBefore) {
      // - continue after already having
      //   encountered a break-command before.
      continueLooping();
    } else {
      // - continue-command while already running which
      //   is equal to skipping  the next occurring cycle.
      ++idx;
    }
  });
  continueLooping();

  return promise;
}
```

...  and finally gets assigned for demonstration purposes via [`Reflect.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/defineProperty) as `forEachAsyncBC` to `Array.prototype` ...

```
Reflect.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'forEachAsyncBC', {
  value: forEachAsyncBreakAndContinue,
});
```

The now prototypal `forEachAsyncBC` method is always going to return a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). This [`Promise` instance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise) either [`reject`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject)s or [`resolve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)s; the former in case the provided callback function does raise an error at any time it gets invoked, and the latter in case the iteration cycle has been fully completed.

Thanks to all the abstractions an executable example code which does test all of the mentioned features can be written as easy as that ...

```js
(async () => {

  const result =  await [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
    .forEachAsyncBC((value, idx, arr, controller) => {

      console.log({ value, idx });

      if (value === 9 || value === 3) {
        console.log(`... skip over next value => ${ arr[idx + 1] } ...`);

        // skip over.
        controller.continue();

      } else  if (value === 4 || value === 6) {

        console.log(`... break at value ${ value } ... continue after 5 seconds ...`);
        setTimeout(controller.continue.bind(controller), 5000);

        // break loop.
        controller.break();
      }
    });

  console.log({ result });

})();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>

class PausedStateSignal extends EventTarget {
  // shared protected/private state.
  #state;

  constructor(connect) {
    super();

    this.#state = {
      isPaused: false,
    };
    connect(this, this.#state);
  }
  get paused() {
    return this.#state.isPaused;
  }
}

class PauseController {
  #signal;
  #signalState;

  constructor() {
    new PausedStateSignal((signal, signalState) => {

      this.#signal = signal;
      this.#signalState = signalState;
    });
    this.#signalState.isPaused = false;
  }
  get signal() {
    return this.#signal;
  }

  break() {
    const isPaused = this.#signalState.isPaused;

    if (!isPaused) {
      this.#signalState.isPaused = true;
    }
    this.#signal.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent('break', { detail: { pausedBefore: isPaused } })
    );
    return !isPaused;
  }
  continue() {
    const isPaused = this.#signalState.isPaused;

    if (isPaused) {
      this.#signalState.isPaused = false;
    }
    this.#signal.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent('continue', { detail: { pausedBefore: isPaused } })
    );
    return isPaused;
  }
}

// - asynchronously implemented `forEach` array method which
//   provides a `PauseController` instance as 4th parameter
//   to its callback function, where the latter's two methods
//   `break` and `continue` enable the following ...
//
//    - pause a `forEach` loop by invoking `break`.
//    - by invoking `continue` ...
//       - either continuing a paused `forEach` loop.
//       - or skipping the `forEach` loop's next iteration step.
//
function forEachAsyncBreakAndContinue(callback, context = null) {
  const { promise, reject, resolve } = Promise.withResolvers();

  const controller = new PauseController;
  const { signal } = controller;

  const arr = this;
  const { length } = arr;

  let idx = -1;

  function continueLooping() {
    while(++idx < length) {

      if (signal.paused) {
        --idx;

        break;
      }
      try {
        callback.call(context, arr.at(idx), idx, arr, controller);

      } catch (exception) {

        reject(exception.message ?? String(exception));
      }
    }
    if (idx >= length) {

      resolve({ success: true });
    }
  }
  signal.addEventListener('continue', ({ detail: { pausedBefore } }) => {
    if (pausedBefore) {
      // - continue after already having
      //   encountered a break-command before.
      continueLooping();
    } else {
      // - continue-command while already running which
      //   is equal to skipping  the next occurring cycle.
      ++idx;
    }
  });
  continueLooping();

  return promise;
}

Reflect.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'forEachAsyncBC', {
  value: forEachAsyncBreakAndContinue,
});

</script>
```