# Understanding a comma statement

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand what the following function returns:

```
fs.api.services.wrapOnSuccess_ = function(a, b, c) {
    if (b) return c = c || function() {},
        function(d, e, f) {
            fs.isDefinedAndNotNull(d.debugtrace) && fs.api.services.handleDebugTrace_(d.debugtrace);
            200 == d.meta.code ? (fs.api.getLogger().debug("success"),
                b(a(d.response), fs.api.services.rawBundleSuccess_(d, e, f))) :
            (fs.api.getLogger().error("non 200 meta code on api response", d), c(d.meta, fs.api.services.rawBundleSuccess_(d, e, f)))
        }
```

Is it right that it returns a ternary function since `function(d,e,f){..}` is on the right of the comma? If so, does it mean calls to `wrapOnSuccess_`  should look something like `wrapOnSuccess_(x,y,z)(s,t,u)`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a comma do in JavaScript expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561043/what-does-a-comma-do-in-javascript-expressions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is minified code. It's not really meant to be understood in the typical sense.

As far as what it returns, if `b` is truthy, it'll return the `function(d, e, f) {` function after assigning either `c` to `c` if `c` was truthy, else the no-op function, to `c`.

So yes, you could invoke the return value immediately *if* `b` was truthy`. Looks like we're missing the rest of the function though.

Keep in mind that the comma operator has the lowest precedence of all operators. That should help figure things out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561043/what-does-a-comma-do-in-javascript-expressions.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez: The OP is asking specifically how it impacts the given function. The operations after the `return` are convoluted, so they weren't sure what exactly was returned.