# prototype function in javascript returns NaN

Tags: javascript, return, prototype, nan

I have this code right here that returns `NaN` for some reason, but when I `console.log` parts of the return it returns an actual number. I tried `Math.floor,`parseInt`, I don't know what to do...

```
nouveauVoyage.prototype.prixGlobalParPersonne = function(){
    var frais=0;
    if (this.voiturePlaces == 0 && this.hotelPlaces == 0){
        frais=0;
    }else if(this.voiturePlaces != 0 && this.hotelPlaces != 0){
        frais=40;
    }else if((this.voiturePlaces != 0 && this.hotelPlaces == 0) || (this.voiturePlaces == 0 && this.hotelPlaces != 0)){
        frais=20;
    }
    return ((this.nbrAdultes * this.prixParPersonne) + ((this.prixParPersonne * this.nbEnfants) * 0,8) + frais) / (this.nbAdultes + this.nbEnfants);
};
```

for more details here's my constructor

```
function nouveauVoyage(type,destination,nbrAdultes,nbrEnfants,prixParPersonne,prixParGroupe,placesVoitures,placesHotel){
        this.id = (new Date().valueOf() + " ").substring(6, 13);
        this.type = type;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.nbrAdultes = parseInt(nbrAdultes);
        this.nbrEnfants = parseInt(nbrEnfants);
        this.prixParPersonne = parseInt(prixParPersonne);
        this.prixParGroupe = parseInt(prixParGroupe);
        this.voiturePlaces = parseInt(placesVoitures);
        this.hotelPlaces = parseInt(placesHotel);
    }
```

and what I pass to it

```
var type = $("select").first().val();
var destination = $("input:radio:checked").val();
var nbAdultes = $("input[type=number]").eq(1).val();
var nbEnfants = $("input[type=number]").eq(2).val();
var prixParPersonne = $("input[type=text]").first().val();
var prixParGroupe = $("input[type=text]").last().val()
prixParPersonne = prixParPersonne.substring(0, prixParPersonne.length-1);
prixParGroupe = prixParGroupe.substring(0, prixParGroupe.length-1);
var placesVoiture = $("input[type=number").eq(-2).val();
var placesHotel = $("input[type=number]").last().val();
var voyage = new nouveauVoyage(type,destination,nbAdultes,nbEnfants,prixParPersonne,prixParGroupe,placesVoiture,placesHotel);
```

Comment: Please post a full example we can debug. There are too many variables there whose value we don't know.

Comment: I think that maybe you are dividing by 0 (so this.nbAdultes + this.nbEnfants == 0 ?)

Comment: For one though, you probably mean `0.8`, not [`0,8`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3561043/476).

Comment: I changed it but it didn't remove the probblem :/, maybe it's the division I honestly don't know

Comment: Might be because you are dividing it by the sum of (nbEnfants and nbAdultes) which is not available for nouveauVoyage.

Please change all nbEnfants to nbrEnfants and all nbAdultes to nbrAdultes inside the function prixGlobalParPersonne

Comment: oops I haven't seen this, thanks

Comment: `NaN` means that you don't have a number. Most likely your `parseInt` call is failing somewhere. Maybe you are passing in a `"0,8"` instead of a `"0.8"` somewhere...

Comment: I've found the problem it was mispelling of property, I don't know how to mark @KumarAman answer as correct