# How does the comma operator work in js?

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword, comma-operator

I'm trying to understand how the comma operator (,) works in JavaScript,
it seems to have a different behaviour when it's not put between parenthesis.

Can someone explain me why ?

Exemple for reference :

```js
var a = 1; 
var b = 2; 
var c = (a,b);
console.log(c);
//output : as expected 
var c = a,b;
console.log(c);
//output : 1
```

---

[EDIT] 
The title might be a bit confusing. 
My question is about a misconception between the coma operator and var attribution as somone explained [further down](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50678579/7930334)

Therefore this subject is **not** a duplicate of that one [What does a comma do in JavaScript expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561043/what-does-a-comma-do-in-javascript-expressions)

Comment: @RameshRajendran — Not a duplicate of that as it doesn't address the second of the two cases the question is asking about the difference between.

Comment: @RameshRajendran It's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> var c = (a,b);
> ```

The above uses the comma operator. It evaluates as the value of its right-hand side (i.e. `b`).

---

> ```
> var c = a,b;
> ```

This does not use the comma *operator*.

The comma character here forms part of the `var` expression which takes a comma-separated list of variables to create in the current scope, each of which can have an optional assignment.

It is equivalent to:

```
var c = a;
var b;
```