# React.js useState() not updating in input

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have 4 inputs that update a react state when there is text typed inside, only one of them tends to update for some reason and I can't find out why, there are no typing errors and I have checked the imports, state names, and inputs to make sure that they work correctly. Is there another factor that I'm missing here? thanks in advance

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

export default function Home() {
  const [a, setA] = useState()
  const [b, setB] = useState()
  const [c, setC] = useState()
  const [d, setD] = useState()
  
  
  return (
    <>
      <input onChange={(e) => setA(e.target.value)} />
      <input onChange={(e) => setB(e.target.value)} />
      <input onChange={(e) => setC(e.target.value)} />
      <input onChange={(e) => setD(e.target.value)} />
      <p style={{color:'white'}}>
        {a, b, c, d}
      </p>
    </>
  );
}
```

I have tried changing the state names to different things, I have retyped all inputs manually multiple times, and I have checked the imports to make sure they work. I have also tried having the states start with (' ') or (), but both didn't work.

Comment: set the value property to the inputs to be the state you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the comma operator work in js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50678527/how-does-the-comma-operator-work-in-js)

Comment: Hi, as @kengru said, add the value property to your inputs:
`
<input onChange={(e) => setA(e.target.value)} value={a} /> 
<input onChange={(e) => setB(e.target.value)} value={b} />
`
You can see the documentation exemple here : https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/input#controlling-an-input-with-a-state-variable

Comment: This is a case of "ignoring console errors", because there is no way this did not raise one. If you're using any kind of IDE i would also think it gave you some kind of warning.

PS: if you're learning then let that be an important lesson: it is always better to try and understand those errors rather than ignoring/dissmissing them.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the state works just fine. You have an other mistake:

You should name the properties separately to display them i.e. `{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}`

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

export default function Home() {
  const [a, setA] = useState()
  const [b, setB] = useState()
  const [c, setC] = useState()
  const [d, setD] = useState()
  
  
  return (
    <>
      <input onChange={(e) => setA(e.target.value)} />
      <input onChange={(e) => setB(e.target.value)} />
      <input onChange={(e) => setC(e.target.value)} />
      <input onChange={(e) => setD(e.target.value)} />
      <p style={{color:'black'}}>
        {a}, {b}, {c}, {d}
      </p>
    </>
  );
}
```

also I had to set the color to black to display the text against a white (default) background.

Answer (score 1):

Writing as `{a, b, c, d}` is giving an error in codesandbox.io:

> JSX expressions may not use the comma operator. Did you mean to write an array?

This only displays the last input, where you are updating `d`'s state. If you would like to display them comma separated, do this: `{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}`.

[image: Edit eloquent-gates-64g4hs]

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks pretty much correct, I believe the problem is the way you try to print the a,b,c,d variables. When you write a JSX expression (everything starting from the `<>` to the `</>` is jsx) what you put within the curly brackets should be a valid javascript expression, it can be a string, a number or many other things. The `{a, b, c, d}` probably does not evaluate in the way you think it is, it you want to have it displayed as strings you can write it as:

```
{"" + a + ", " + b + ", " + c + ", " + d}
```

Which is a valid JS code that evaluate to a string that contains a,b,c,d with comma separation.

Comment: The suggestion of leonardkraemer is also great:
you can just put a-b in a set of curly braces each (like this {a}) and then add the commas between.