# Making a function range, with 3 parameters, with exceptions?

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I am trying to make a function called range which takes 3 integer parameters: start, end, and step.

The function should return an array of numbers from start to end counting by step.

The function should return an empty array if given incorrect parameters, such as:

Start, end, or step being undefined. 
Start being greater than end. 
Step being negative.

This is my code:

```
const range = function(start, end, step) {
  const result = []
  for (let i = start; i <= end; i += step) {
    return i || end || step == undefined ? []
                                        : i > end ? []
                                                  : step < 0 ? []
                                                            : result.push(i)
    }
  return result;
}

console.log(range(0, 10, 2));
console.log(range(10, 30, 5));
console.log(range(-5, 2, 3));
```

All of these return an empty array.

I am new to JavaScript, so please...the more you explain, the more you help me.

Thank you.

Comment: `I am new to Java` A suggestion: learn the name of the language you're writing in

Comment: Looks familiar, except for the error handling: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51777264/looping-range-step-by-step

Comment: Reformatted your code : helps to show the structure. Suggestion: multiple condition operators are hard to follow so generally they are avoided.

Comment: What would be a good way of writing the conditions?

Comment: I recommend to read about `clean code` :-) there are so many `if` statements, that it surely can be written more human-friendly :-) I believe that when you will split all those `?` operations to separate pieces of code, you will get better understanding of your own code :-)

Comment: @ChrisGardner: see the answers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that

```
return i || end || step == undefined ? []
```

will test for the truthyness of `i`, or for the truthyness of `end`, or for if `step` is `undefined`. If either `i` or `end` are positive numbers (among other things), the entire condition will evaluate to `true`, and the empty array will be returned.

If you want to check to see if any of the arguments are undefined, you might use `.some`, passing in an array of the arguments.

You also shouldn't `return` *inside* the `for` loop - test to see if the inputs are invalid *first* and return if invalid. Then, iterate through the loop, pushing to `result`, and once the loop finishes, return the `result`. For example, here's one possible implementation:

```js
const range = function(start, end, step) {
  if (
    [start, end, step].some(arg => arg === undefined)
    || start > end
    || step < 0
  ) {
    return [];
  }
  const result = []
  for (let i = start; i <= end; i += step) {
    result.push(i)
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(range(10, 0, 3));
console.log(range(0, 10, 2));
console.log(range(10, 30, 5));
console.log(range(-5, 2, 3));
```

Comment: plus 1 for this [start, end, step].some(arg => arg === undefined) :)

Answer (score 0):

The first step in the `for` loop is a `return`. This will exit the function.

The expression on the `return` will return `start` (the initial value of `i`) unless it is zero, in which case `end` will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const range = function(start, end, step) {
  const result = []
  for (let i = start; i <= end; i += step) {
    i==undefined ? [] : end==undefined
    ? [] : step==undefined 
    ? [] : i > end 
    ? [] : step < 0 
    ? [] : result.push(i)
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(range(10, 0, 3));
console.log(range(0, 10, 2));
console.log(range(10, 30, 5));
console.log(range(-5, 2, 3));
```