# How does Promise.all with comma operator between array and object work?

Tags: javascript, promise

I've come across this piece of code:

```js
const results = await Promise.all(
                          [ Model1.find({}), Model2.find({}) ],
                          Model3.find({})
                      ),
        v1 = results[0],
        v2 = results[1],
        v3 = results[2]
```

which is invoking `all()` with an array and a single object — `*Model* are Mongoose models*.

This is an easily fixed bug, but I'd like to understand how it is giving the resulting values, which are:

- v1 holds all the documents corresponding to `Model1`
- v2 holds all the documents corresponding to `Model2`
- v3 is `undefined`

As explained in [this answer on the comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561056/3127111), I expected only the `Model3.find({})` promise to actually return data in `results`, as the comma operator should evaluate the first operand but return its second operand (to `Promise.all()`). But it's instead the other way around: `results[0]` and `results[1]` both contain data, while `results[2]` (and thus `v3`) is `undefined`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a *parameter list* rather than a single expression, so the comma operator does not apply - the array

```
[Model1.find({}), Model2.find({})]
```

is evaluated as the first argument passed to `Promise.all`, and the second argument is

```
Model3.find({})
```

But `Promise.all` only accepts one parameter, an iterable; the second parameter of `Model3` is just ignored, and the result is just `[Model1.find({}), Model2.find({})]` mapped to their resolve values. Since the passed array only has two values, the `Promise.all` resolves to an array which also has only two values (index `[2]` is `undefined`).

If you had enclosed the `Promise.all` call in *another* set of parentheses:

```
const results = await Promise.all((
  [ Model1.find({}), Model2.find({}) ],
  Model3.find({})
))
```

then you *would* be invoking the comma operator, because everything inside the second set of parentheses would get evaluated as a *single expression* while the interpreter attempts to come up with a value for the first (and only) parameter to be passed to the `Promise.all`. (But `Promise.all` accepts an *iterable*, not a `Promise`, so the evaluation of the comma operator:

```
await Promise.all((
  Model3.find({})
))
```

would then result in an error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: So... it all boils down to js [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Answer (score 3):

Your function call

```
Promise.all([ Model1.find({}), Model2.find({}) ], Model3.find({}))
//          ^-     First parameter            -^  ^- second    -^
```

You have passed only two promises to the [**Promise.all**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) function -

1. first two as an array - `[Model1.find({}), Model2.find({})]`.
2. `Model3` as the second parameter - `Model3.find({})`.

`Model3` is passed but it is ignored by function - function takes only **one parameter** - the first one which must be an ***iterable***

### Syntax

`Promise.all(iterable);`

---

`Promise.all` just runs those promises which are defined in the first parameter and you get only results for `Model1.find({})` and `Model2.find({})`.

You think that `results[2]` is the result of `Model3.find({})`, but not. In this case it is an array which contains 2 items - results of two promises which are passed via *array/iterable*. When you want to access an index of the array which is greater then it's `length - 1`, you will get `undefined`.

### Function parameters

In JavaScript you can pass to function how many arguments you want, but parameters will be assigned from left to right and those arguments which does not fit in the range of the parameters will be just ignored.

Look at the below example. I have passed 5 arguments to the function, but my function takes only first two, so the `3, 4, 5` are just ignored. You have this case.

```js
function foo(a, b) {
   console.log(a, b);
}

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Comment: Both are good answers, I chose the other one because it more clearly mentions the comma operator is not involved.