# error with div style = “value%” as it is not executing

Tags: javascript

I tried get a width with a calculation in it to determine the width size, however the 15.4% value just keeps appearing on my page and it is not executing in the div statement as the width: 15.4%.

```
var percent = (154 / 1000) *100;
var percent1 = percent + "%";


$('#bar').append("<div id='barbox_a'></div>" +
"<div class='bar blank'></div>" + "<div class='bar' style='width: ",
 percent1, " '>" + "</div>\n");
```

Comment: I assume you meant to write `"<div class='bar' style='width: " +
 percent1 + " '>" + "</div>\n"`, not `"<div class='bar' style='width: ",
 percent1, " '>" + "</div>\n"`?

Comment: thanks a lot! yeah that works

Comment: In JS the comma operator evaluates each comma-delimited expression and returns the last one. So your original code just returned `'></div>`, hence your error.

Comment: Uh, the PHP tag doesn't belong here, but javascript does

Comment: More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561043/what-does-a-comma-do-in-javascript-expressions) about the comma operator.

Comment: @DarraghEnright yeah i didnt realise the closing and opening was wrong

Comment: @Smankusors yeah i placed the wrong tag