# Javascript: Iterate through array and modify items inside the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to set up a function on my page that will iterate through a series of news titles and will strikethrough the title if it contains a specific marker.

The titles are pulled from a WordPress post database and displayed within a `<div>` with `ID="news"`. Each specific title is a link `<a>` with `class="title"`. 
I am first collecting all the titles into an array so I can iterate through them but for some reason, it doesn't work properly.

My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//first I create the array
var test_DOM = document.getElementById("news").getElementsByClassName("title");
//then I set the marker
var marker = "[X]"
//then I wirte the function to iterate through the array://
function checkX() {
for(i in test_DOM){
if (i.includes(marker)) {
i = "<del>", i, "</del>";
console.log(test_DOM[i], "changed")
}
console.log(test_DOM[i].innerHTML)
}
};
//and I call the function
checkX()
```

An expected result would be to see the list of news to change from

```
[x] News 1
[EG] News 2
```

to

```
[x] News 1 <- struck through
[EG] News 2 <- still the same
```

However, nothing happens. I know that getElementsByClassName gets me an array of objects and that I should use .innerHTML and some point, but using it inside the function like

```
function checkX() {
for(i in test_DOM){
if (i.innerHTML.includes(marker)) {
i.innerHTML = "<del>", i, "</del>";
console.log(test_DOM[i], "changed")
}
console.log(test_DOM[i].innerHTML)
}
};
```

gives an error of "TypeError: i.innerHTML is undefined"

Comment: `i = "<del>", i, "</del>";` does not combine the strings, it uses the [comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561043/what-does-a-comma-do-in-javascript-expressions) and returns only the last item. Also `i` would not be each *value* of `test_DOM` but each *key* from `test_DOM`.

Comment: Did you check for errors in the browser console?  Also, getElementsByClassName() returns a "NodeList" object, not an array as may be expected, so running a for in loop over it will run over all properties, not just item indexes. The NodeList object does contain a length property that corresponds to the length of indeces though, so a notmal for loop like this should work. `for (i = 0; i < test_DOM.length; i++)`

Comment: @Kik4s Hey, just a friendly reminder to mark an answer as "accepted" if it answered your question. If the 2 existing answers below don't quite answer your question, you can leave a comment to get some more clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to do and have a solution for you. There are a few things that need to be updated to get the script working as you described:

1. Your DOM query can be shortened using `document.querySelectorAll`.
2. When using `String.includes()`, it is case sensitive. This means that `[x]` is not equal to `[X]`, so be sure to check the correct version for your test.
3. As @2pha mentioned in their comment, `test_DOM` will return a `NodeList`, which is an array-like structure, but not quite an array. To convert it to an array that can be looped over as you intend, you can use `[].slice.call(test_DOM)`.
4. As @VLAZ mentioned in their comment, the comma operator will not combine strings. You should use the `'string' + 'string'` syntax to combine strings.
5. Also as @VLAZ mentioned, the `for...in` loop is more intended for objects, in which it will output the keys of the object, not the values, so this isn't appropriate for your use case. You can use `Array.forEach()` instead.
6. As you alluded to, the `Array.includes()` check should use `innerHTML` for its check, and `innerHTML` should be used to then reset the value of the element.

I included a snippet below with some modifications.

```js
var test_DOM = document.querySelectorAll('#news .title');
var marker = '[x]';

function checkX() {
  [].slice.call(test_DOM).forEach(function(elem, i) {
    if(elem.innerHTML.includes(marker)) {
      elem.innerHTML = '<del>' + elem.innerHTML + '</del>';
    }
  });
}

checkX()
```

```html
<div id="news">
  <h1 class="title">[x] News 1</h1>
  <h1 class="title">[EG] News 2</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow on from my comment.
ie. "getElementsByClassName() returns a "NodeList" object, not an array as may be expected". But does have a length property.
The minimal changes to your code to get it to work.

```js
//first I create the array
var test_DOM = document.getElementById("news").getElementsByClassName("title");
//then I set the marker
var marker = "[X]"
//console.log(test_DOM);
//then I wirte the function to iterate through the array://
function checkX() {
  for(i = 0; i < test_DOM.length; i++){
    if (test_DOM[i].innerHTML.includes(marker)) {
      test_DOM[i].innerHTML = "<del>" + test_DOM[i].innerHTML + "</del>";
      //console.log(test_DOM[i], "changed")
    }
    //console.log(test_DOM[i].innerHTML)
  }
};
//and I call the function
checkX();
```

```html
<div id="news">
<h2 class="title">title 1</h2>
<h2 class="title">[X]title 2</h2>
<h2 class="title">title 3</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: jackrugile's answer is more indepth than mine (an probably should be the accepted answer), but mine should allow you to easily understand why your specific code was not working.