# How to access two parameters one being an array the other being a value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, ecmascript-6, reduce

trying to write a function that takes the change you have in an array `[quarters,dimes,nickels,pennies]` and second parameter of the cost value `n`.
So (`[quarters,dimes,nickels,pennies],n`)
then I wanna use the reduce method to create an ES6 style of code

I  want to understand how to use reduce and grab the second parameter in my code

```js
const changeEnough = ([25, 20, 5, 0], 4.25)
const ct = (accumulator, currentValue) => 
    ((accumulator + currentValue) - intialValue >= 0);

console.log(changeEnough.reduce(ct));
```

error message I am getting is

```
changeEnough.reduce is not a function
```

I have figured that I am not asking the other value of 4.25 in my code

Comment: You're using the comma operator, which has `changeEnough` evaluate to `4.25`, discarding the initial array

Comment: Can you elaborate more please?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561043/what-does-a-comma-do-in-javascript-expressions . Don't use the comma operator

Comment: Basically `changeEnough` is becoming the number  `4.25`, which isn't an array and doesn't contain the `.reduce()` function. Which is why you are getting `changeEnough.reduce is not a function`

Comment: Also, doing a comparison inside the lambda results in a boolean value instead of a numeric which is then added to a numeric value. You probably want the comparison outside the reduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your declaration of `changeEnough` is wrong. Using the comma operator like that results in the final value - what actually *is* it? `4.25`:

```js
const changeEnough = ([25, 20, 5, 0], 4.25);
console.log(changeEnough);
```

So pass the second value as a second argument to `reduce`. You can make this simple by using an array for `changeEnough`:

```
const changeEnough = [[25, 20, 5, 0], 4.25];
const ct = (accumulator, currentValue) => ((accumulator + currentValue) - intialValue >= 0);

console.log(changeEnough[0].reduce(ct, changeEnough[1]));
```

<sub>(Also make sure you've defined `initialValue`.)</sub>