# How do return statements with double parentheses work?

Tags: javascript, return, return-value, openpgp.js

Inside the OpenPGP.js module is this line of code:

```
return (0, _message.createVerificationObjects)
     (signatureList, [literalDataPacket], keys, date, true)
```

**1.**

`createVerificationObjects` is a function so I assume the following parenthetic are the values it requires. Why format this as

```
(function)(arguments)
```

instead of the traditional

```
(function(arguments))
```

**2.**

How can a return statement contain multiple values?

`return (0, createVerificationObjects)`

Shouldn't you be forced to choose between returning `0` or `createVerificationObjects`?

Comment: `(0, createVerificationObjects)` isn't multiple values it evaluates to `(createVerificationObjects)` the last value in the comma separated list. See this q&a: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561043/what-does-a-comma-do-in-javascript-expressions

Comment: "*How can a return statement contain multiple values?*" it's not multiple values, this is [a comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561043/what-does-a-comma-do-in-javascript-expressions)

Comment: @PatrickEvans That question explains how the comma operator works, but doesn't justify the way it's used here. See the duplicate that ASDFGerte pointed out.

Comment: @Barmar I know i wasnt using it to justify its use. Just letting them know that `return (0,createVerificationObjects)` wasn't trying to return multiple things, their question 2