# Can anyone explain why the below code is printing 5?

Tags: javascript

```js
//Function getNumber
function getNumber() {
  return (2, 4, 5);
}
var numb = getNumber();
console.log(numb); //5
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does a comma do in JavaScript expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561043/what-does-a-comma-do-in-javascript-expressions)

Comment: because `(2, 4, 5)`  = 5.