# Why h1 doesn't appear when run this code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following React render function:

```
render() {
  return (
    <h1>Post list</h1>,
    this.state.posts_data.map(p =>
      <div key={p.id}>
        {p.title} , {p.id} , {p.userId}
      </div>
    )
  );
}
```

Why does the h1 not appear when run the code?

Comment: See https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-fragments-in-react-a1b6e534b01a

Comment: The reason why it doesn't crash but the `h1` is not rendered is because you're returning an [expression that uses the comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3561043/1218980)

Comment: @EmileBergeron yes this answer the question . thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can only return 1 element, in your case you have 2 options, you can wrap all your elements in a single `<div>` like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Post list</h1>,
      {this.state.posts_data.map(p =>
        <div key={p.id}>
          {p.title} , {p.id} , {p.userId}
        </div>
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

or you can use `<React.Fragment />`.

```
render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Post list</h1>,
      {this.state.posts_data.map(p =>
        <div key={p.id}>
          {p.title} , {p.id} , {p.userId}
        </div>
      }
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Note: In React we use JSX, so if you want to use Javascript with your HTML you have to wrap it in `{ }`, which is why I've wrapped your `this.state.posts_data.map()` in those brackets.

Make sure that `this.state.posts_data` is an Array or else this will throw an error.

Comment: Also, the comma is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrite the code using array concept and the problem solved

```
 render() {
        return (
               [
                <h1>Post list</h1>,
                this.state.posts_data.map(p =>
                <div key={p.id}>
                    {p.title} , {p.id} , {p.userId}
                </div>
                )
               ]
        );

    }
```

Comment: That's actually what a `React.Fragment` is in the background. ;) Both can be used and that's also mean that a component can return the result from e.g. `.map` directly.

Comment: Sure , but I find using [] simple and easy :) .

Comment: @sameerRezaKhan ")" is true , it is the close tag from map function

Comment: @EmileBergeron Sure , but I find using [] simple and easy :) .

Comment: @EmileBergeron I tried the fragment way instead of [] , but I get error in p , it said not defined .. what is the problem ?

Answer (score -1):

You have to wrap both elements in one tag. Render can only return one.

Comment: I tried your idea , and get error in p ,  why ?

Answer (score -1):

I have modified your code.

```
render() { 
    return ( 
        [
            <h1>Post list</h1>, 
            this.state.posts_data.map(p => (
                  <div key={p.id}> 
                      {p.title} , {p.id} , {p.userId} 
                  </div>
               ) 
            )
        ]
    );
}
```

When you have multi element but you don't want them to wrap in a single parent node, you need to push them to array. 
Also you need to use curly braces around your js code within jsx.

Comment: Tell me what is wrong with answer

Comment: This idea solve my problem .. but you have "{" cause error .. you can see my answer

Comment: I wrote when to use {,}, and if it solves your problem then why a downvote?

Comment: I downvoted since the `{}` are used incorrectly here.

Comment: You could have suggested edit. But anyway, i would take it, that was my mistake.