# Is comma a terminator or a separator in JavaScript inside object and array literals and in a functions parameter list?

Tags: javascript, syntax

In the Go language, a trailing comma is required when creating a struct object, so in Go a comma is a terminator.

```golang
var a mystruct = {
  a: 5,
  b: 6,
}
```

In the Rust language, it seems to be good style to treat commas like terminators, but the language also allows them to be like separators, it's up to you.

In JavaScript, it used to behave like a separator only. However, newer versions of JavaScript allow trailing commas.

```js
let a = {
  a: 5,
  b: 5,
};
```

- Does the JavaScript spec still consider a comma to be a "separator" (inside object and array literals and function parameter list) or do they now consider it either a "separator" or a "terminator"?
- Is it wrong for me to say that the comma is a "terminator" in the example above?

Comment: You should add more context. In what context do you think trailing commas are required in Go? Could you add code examples?

Comment: Can you give some context for the trailing commas? Seems like you're talking about the array and object literal syntax but there is also the [comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561043/what-does-a-comma-do-in-javascript-expressions) which is a completely separate thing.

Comment: "*Is it wrong for me to say that a comma is a "terminator"?*" I'd say yes - very wrong. I'm not really sure if we're talking about the same thing, though. Can you give a sample code where you'd call a comma a terminator?

Comment: Commas are allowed to trail in arrays and objects. They are not terminators, just trailing separators

Comment: If by "terminator" you mean "line terminator", then no, a comma is not a line terminator: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-line-terminators . I also don't think it's a terminator in other languages, otherwise would `[]{1,2,3}` be valid in Go?

Comment: If these terms would have absolute meaning everybody agrees to one might be able to answer your question.

Comment: @Volker assuming separator means that it goes in between, and terminator means it goes at the end of each

Answer (score 2):

A trailing comma is not a terminator in JS

JS does not "allow trailing commas"

```js
var a,b,c,

function test() {}
```

It allows trailing separators:

```js
console.log(["a",",b","c",])
```

Comment: Sorry I edited my question, I meant in the case of object literals and array literals and function call parameters

Comment: My answer remains. A trailing comma is a trailing separator