# Spreading operator doesn't work the same as assigning an object in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jsx

When I do the following, everything works fine:

`this.state.sections.map(({ a, b }) => <MenuItem { ...{a,b} }/>)`

However, when I do the following(which I think would be the equivalent, I get an error saying `...` is expected:

`this.state.sections.map(({ a, b }) => <MenuItem { a, b }/>)`

Why so? Isn't `...{a,b}` the equivalent of `a, b` in JS?

Comment: "*Isn't `...{a,b}` the equivalent of `a, b` in JS?*" No, it's not. One creates a new object, the other is using the [comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561043/what-does-a-comma-do-in-javascript-expressions) which would ignore `a` and just gives you `b`. However, that's for *JavaScript*, the React syntax here might be a different thing - I'm not well versed in it.

Comment: @VLAZ so the equivalent of `...{a,b}` is `{a,b}`, right?

Comment: the brackets in the case of { a, b } are used to denote a javascript expression as a prop in JSX (executing `a, b` as a prop, which is invalid because the prop has no name), whereas the ...{a,b} is simulating a spread operator onto props, where the key names are used as prop names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not equivalent in JSX context:

```
// For given function component
const MenuItem = ({ a, b }) => <></>

// Use cases
(props /* {a,b} */) => <MenuItem {...props} />
<MenuItem a={a} b={b} />
<MenuItem { ...{a,b} }/>

// Transpiles to
React.createElement(MenuItem, { a, b });
```

```
// Syntax Error
// as this JSX doesn't transpile to React.createElement 
<MenuItem {a, b} />

/*
Unexpected token, expected "..." (1:11)
> 1 | <MenuItem {a, b} />;
*/
```

But in JS they do result the same structure:

```
a = 5;
b= 7;
{ a, b } // { a: 5, b: 7 }
{ ...{ a, b } // { a: 5, b: 7 }
```

Be aware of the difference between code transpiled by babel compiler and JS.

- See [babel playground](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DwWQpgdgrgkgLmAtgAgN4EMA0yBGBfZAegD4BuIA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=react&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.9.0&externalPlugins=) to check the results.
- [JSX in Depth](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)