# Why does having a trailing value on an object literal return that value?

Tags: javascript, object-literal

I can do:

`{test : 10}`

But how is this valid JS and why do I get 7 when I add this to the chrome js console?

`{test: 10, 7}`

How is this trailing 7 valid if it doesn't have a key?

Is this a special JS object literal syntax? Where can I read more about it and why it evaluated to 7?

When I do:
`const test = {test: 10, 7}; // VM140:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'`

That gives me a expected error so how come without assigning it to a variable it is valid JS and the console returns to me the value 7?

When I do:

`{test: 10, 7, 8}`

I then get 8

I also get an error if I try JSON notation:

`{'test': 10, 7}`

Whats going on here?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does a comma do in JavaScript expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561043/what-does-a-comma-do-in-javascript-expressions)

Comment: confusing thing is Block VS Object and how the code is seen based on the content. You have a label https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label inside of a block

Answer (score 1):

The object isn’t relevant; the not very useful comma operator returns the last value.

```
console.log( (10, 7) ) // 7
```

We need extra parentheses here so that it’s not interpreted as a second argument to 'console.log`, but the same thing is happening.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things happening here, but the key thing is that this is not a JavaScript object literal. As you've seen, `const test = {test: 10, 7}` fails.

Firstly, `{let foo=7;}` is valid code; the braces are being used as [block scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), not object notation.

Secondly, `test: statement` is being used to [label a statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), not as a key in an object. This is why quoting `'test'` also fails.

So your code is the same as:

```
{
    test:
    (10, 7)
}
```