# If you put two functions in onClick in React, only one of them will work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the following code, I have two functions in the onClick of a div: `() => this.delete(this, this.state.id)` and  `this.props.deleteTodo.bind(this, this.state.id)`. However, when I put both of them in at the same time, only one of them works.

If I limit it to one of them, it works fine, but why doesn't it work when I add both?

```
<div onClick={() => this.delete(this, this.state.id), this.props.deleteTodo.bind(this, this.state.id)}>button</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561043/what-does-a-comma-do-in-javascript-expressions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap them in curly braces and you should end lines with semi colons and not commas:

```
<div onClick={() => { 
    this.delete(this, this.state.id);
    this.props.deleteTodo.bind(this, this.state.id); 
}}>button</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I tried that method before, but it only executes `this.delete(this, this.state.id);`.

Comment: Then something else is wrong. Here's an example that illustrates that both functions run https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-2xqxq?file=/index.js

Answer (score 0):

For better readability and to avoid errors such as syntax errors, combine them both in a single function and call that function or as [simnys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4166744/simnys) answer.