# A function which takes an array as argument, with a forEach loop which console.log each element and each index for every iteration inside the function

Tags: javascript, function, loops, foreach

I have to create a function which takes an array as argument, with a forEach loop which console.log each element and each index for every iteration inside the function. Also inside the function declare a variable called count, and increment it by one for each iteration then return count.

```
//======================  EXAMPLE  ========================
looper([2,4,8,7])
4 // <======  EXPECTED OUTPUT
//=========================================================
```

I wrote this function:

```
function looper(arr) {
    arr.forEach(function console (item, index){
        var count = 0;
        count++;
        console.log(("I am item ", item, "I am the index ", index));
        return count;
    })
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
VM76:5 Uncaught TypeError: console.log is not a function
    at console (<anonymous>:5:17)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at looper (<anonymous>:2:9)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

How is it that console.log is not a function? Isn't it prebuilt into every browser?

Comment: You named your callback 'console', instead just pass an anonymous function, also, returning from `forEach()` has no effect, it always returns `undefined` per its definition.

Comment: As @pilchard said you named you function console so thats why `.log` does not exist on it also your return statement has to be outside of the `forEach` loop to return the value

Comment: you can't use `console` as name's function.  replace to : `arr.forEach(function(item, index){`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `count` should be declared and returned outside the `forEach()` callback function. Otherwise you reset it to `0` each time through the loop. And the return value of `forEach()` is not returned by the containing function.
2. The error about `console.log` not being defined is because you named the callback function `console`. That shadows the global `console` object. There's no need to give a name to the callback function.
3. You shouldn't put an extra set of parentheses around the arguments to `console.log()`. This makes them an expression using the [comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561043/what-does-a-comma-do-in-javascript-expressions), so it only logs the last item in each call.

```js
function looper(arr) {
  var count = 0;
  arr.forEach(function(item, index) {
    count++;
    console.log("I am item ", item, "I am the index ", index);
  })
  return count;
}

console.log(looper([1, 3, 4, 10]));
```