# How to use await and promise.all

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

If the a and b promise functions exist, do the two codes below work the same?

```js
await Promise.all([a(), b()]);

await (a(), b());
```

Comment: What happens when you test it?

Comment: The second one is just the comma operator, it's not anywhere near awaiting both: [What does the comma operator do in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3561043)

Comment: `Promise.all([..])` returns a promise Object, so using it with await is similar to when you call the promise object with `.then().catch()`

Comment: The simple answer is No.  It will just wait for `b`, and `a` will be left as a promise to resolve.  Were as `await Promise.all` is going to wait for `a` and `b` to resolve, and return the resolved results in an array..