# What is this python tuple-like syntax in Javascript actually doing?

Tags: javascript, variables, syntax

What is going on in this Javascript code? Is there a name for this or some place to learn more about the specific behavior illustrated?

I didn't think coding a "tuple" in JS would be valid syntax, but it seems to be. However the resulting variable definitely doesn't behave as a tuple, which is expected given JS's lack of support for them.

It's behavior seems very odd to me though.

It only gets 1 of the two values stored into it, and strangely removing the parenthesis is still valid javascript but ends up storing the opposite value into the varible

```
-> x = (90, 27);
<- 27
-> x
<- 27

-> x = 90, 27;
<- 27
-> x
<- 90
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the comma operator do in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561043/what-does-the-comma-operator-do-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) returns the last element

No tuples in JavaScript

Answer (score 3):

It is just javascript evaluating expression, when you have parenthesis () javascript will evaluate the whole expression inside the parenthesis first and then assign it to the variable since x = (1,2) 2 is the last evaluated value will be assigned to x. But if you don't have parenthesis then it evaluates step by step expression x = 1,2 the first expression it finds is  x=1 and then just evaluates 2 it's as if you typed x=1; 2;

Answer (score 1):

That's not a tuple. JavaScript does not have tuples. You're simply doing

```
x = 90, 27
```

but wrapping the expression `90, 27` in parentheses.
The reason why it's returning 27 is because that's the last element.