# Confused about comma separated functions looking at chrome extension code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm attempting to learn more about chrome extensions and the best way I learn is by looking at stuff that works and trying to understand what it is doing. Well I've gotten a decent understanding of one I've been looking at but I see quite a few odd things that I'm not really sure why they are written that way. Here is a snippet of what I'm looking at:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((o, s, c) => {
  c(),
  (function(o, s, c) {
    <code>
  })
  (o.url, o.headers)
});
```

What I don't understand is why the first 2 statements are separated by a comma while the 3rd is just wrapped in parenthesis. If I remove the comma, then there is an error in the console stating

> Error in event handler: TypeError: c(...) is not a function

It almost seems like somehow that is linking the c function with the function after the comma. I really don't know what is happening with it and it's not the only place that I see it. In the background.js the `chrome.webRequest.onSendHeaders.addListener()` is separated by a comma from the next function of `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener()`

```
chrome.webRequest.onSendHeaders.addListener(
  <code>
),
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  <other code>
)
```

Tried to look up as best I could but couldn't quite find anything that answered my question. Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: The third are arguments to the anonymous function. Arguments have to be in parentheses.

Comment: This seems to be minified code that has been formatted more neatly, they've used commas instead of the normal semicolons between expressions. See the [comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561043/what-does-a-comma-do-in-javascript-expressions)

Comment: The code was minified when I opened it from the chrome folder, I used a website to unminify it, so that would make sense. So it might be possible to replace them with a semicolon?

Comment: You shouldn't try to learn from minified code, because that's going to be very frustrating. Better to find non-minified and well-commented code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially equivalent to this code:

The minified code is using the comma operator instead of semicolon between statements.

It's using an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) to create a nested variable scope for `<code>`. `(o.url, o.headers)` are the arguments to the IIFE. In modern ES6 syntax this can be done using a block and `let` variable bindings.

I've renamed the `o` parameter to the listener to `o1` so it doesn't conflict with the `o` variable in the nested block.

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((o1, s, c) => {
  c(); 
  {
    let o = o1.url;
    let s = o1.headers;
    let c;
    // <code>
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! So it just looks like because it was minified code that I'm not quite familiar with. It definitely makes much  more sense now.

Comment: Yes, also because block scope is an ES6 enhancement to the language. In the past, IIFEs were used for this purpose.