# After editing my input, assigning an id function does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a todolist JavaScript code, after editing my task input, my checkbox function which is assigning an id to be line-through does not work. When i checked the checkbox, it works correctly line through my task.

```js
addNewTask.addEventListener('click', addTask);

function addTask(e) {

    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.className = "list-group-item";
    tasks.appendChild(li);

    const label = document.createElement("label");
    label.className = "form-check-label";
    label.innerText = addInput.value;
    label.type = "text";
    label.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
    li.appendChild(label);

    const checkBox = document.createElement("input")
    checkBox.className = "form-check-input me-1 fa-pull-right"
    checkBox.type = "checkbox"
    checkBox.name = "chk"
    li.appendChild(checkBox);
    checkBox.id = "checkBox";

    const i2=document.createElement("i");
    i2.className="fa-regular fa-pen-to-square fa-pull-right";
    i2.id="editIcon"
    li.appendChild(i2);
    
    checkBox.addEventListener("change",checkedEvent);
    i2.addEventListener("click",editInput);

}

function editInput(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("fa-pen-to-square")) {
        editIcon.className = "fa-solid fa-floppy-disk fa-pull-right";
        const label = li.firstElementChild;
        const input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'text';
        input.value = label.textContent;
        li.insertBefore(input, label);
        li.removeChild(label);
    } else if (e.target.classList.contains("fa-floppy-disk")) {
        const input = li.firstElementChild;
        const label = document.createElement('label');
        label.className = "form-check-label";
        label.textContent = input.value;
        li.insertBefore(label, input);
        li.removeChild(input);
        editIcon.className = "fa-regular fa-pen-to-square fa-pull-right";
    }
}

function checkedEvent() {

    if (checkBox.checked == true && label.className == "form-check-label") {
        label.id = ("id", "completed");
    } else {
        label.id = ("");
    }
}
```

```css
#completed{
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="addNewTask" >Add new task</button>
```

I think my new label element in editInput function does not see as old label element I created in addTask function.

Comment: `label.id = ("id", "completed");` most likely [does not do what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561043/javascript-syntax-what-comma-means) EDIT: although that problem is superseded by `checkedEvent()` never being called. EDIT2: well, *none* of those functions is called. Neither `checkedEvent()`, nor `editInput()`, nor `addTask()`.

Comment: actually i didnt add eventlisteners they all called

Comment: Everytime you add a task, it creates li, label, checkbox with the same attributes.

Comment: `checkBox.checked == true` is not correct. Lookup the [checked option mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#checked). The correct value when checkbox is active is `"on"` and not `true`

Comment: @BenjaJorquera yes

Comment: @AdrienVillalonga thats not the issue sir, this function already works correctly, the case  is after editing the input its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Are there multiple li with the "items" ID? If the function is looking for a specific ID and the ID isn't unique, you may run into issues.

Relevant link: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: no, actually i dont even use id attribute

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).