# Javascript: if(arg1, arg2, arg3...) statement

Tags: javascript

Just bumped into the fact that an `if` statement can have multiple parameters in javascript:

```
// Webkit
if (true, true, false) console.log("this won't get logged");
```

How well is this supported?

p.s. I get that this is similar to using `&&`, but this is interesting and a *google* couldn't provide the answer.

Comment: Using this syntax in production code is one of the 7 deadly programming sins.

Comment: Can you please provide the source for where you found that? Not that I don't believe you, but this looks interesting.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703896/as3-javascript-if-statement-commas-instead-of

Comment: essentially this is only useful in code-golfed JavaScript

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If statements can't have "multiple parameters". What you observed is the use of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/Comma_Operator).

> The comma operator evaluates both of its operands (from left to right)
>   and returns the value of the second operand.

Now we see why `(true, true, false)` doesn't log anything whereas `(true, false, true)` will. As a side note, this syntax is ubiquitously supported (but should almost never be used).

Comment: Wait! So why does it need to evaluate when it's simply returning the second operand?

Comment: @gAMBOOKa: In the example, not at all. When the left expression has side effects, precisely for those.

Comment: I am afraid I don't fully understand it. What do you mean 'has side effects'?

Comment: @gAMBOOKa, `destroy_the_world(), true` will evaluate to `true` but also destroy the world.

Comment: yip. tick tock, before the world ends and when SO lets me answer, I will mark this correct.

Comment: Ah! My interpretation of 'evaluate' was 'compare'... stupid me!

Comment: `i = 10, i === 10` evaluates to true, since the left side has the side-effect of assigning the number 10 to i. `i === 0, i = 10` evaluates to 10, and is the same as just writing `i = 10`, since  the left side has no side-effect.

Comment: I wouldn't say "almost never."  It's convenient in some cases, like multiple initializations in a for loop.

Comment: @Matthew every style guide I've read for the several companies I've worked for has denounced using the comma operator. I think it's rather widely regarded as difficult/cryptic to understand.

Comment: @David, I've read several places ([this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703896/as3-javascript-if-statement-commas-instead-of/703915#703915) being just one) that it is idiomatic to use it in a for loop initialization as I described.

Answer (score 6):

That is not a feature of the `if` statement, it's the `,` operator.

You can separate expressions with a comma, and each expression will be evaluated but only the last one is used as value of the whole expressions.

In your example it's pretty useless, but sometimes you want an expression evaluated for it's side effects. Example:

```
var i = 1;
if (i += 2, i == 3) console.log("this will get logged");
```

Comment: Oooooh, I wish I could upvote again after that edit haha, nice example

Comment: Why can you not use `var` inside the `if()` as you can with `for()`? (I know this doesn't relate to your specific example, but just wondering?)

Comment: @w3d: That is a special feature in the first expression in the `for` statement, which is there because you often need a variable for the loop.

Answer (score 3):

It's not similar to `&&` (try moving the `false` to the first or second place), it has nothing to do with `if`, and it's about as well supported as function literals, i.e. absolutely universally. What you encountered is the comma operator inherited from C, that evaluated the expressions (actually, it's always two expressions and using more conceptually leads to nesting like `a + b + c` does) from left to right and throws away all except the last result. The last result becomes the result of the whole expression.

Answer (score 1):

Works in IE7 so  I guess this is well supported.

Comment: Relying on IE to evaluate standards?

Comment: Nope - its the LCD (lowest common denominator) test. If any feature is likely to break, its probably IE 6 or 7!  :D

Comment: About 50% of the time if something does worksin IE it's not going to work anywhere else haha :P, they like to do things their own way. Obviously the comma operator works in all browsers. It was part of Javascript 1.0, and if I'm not mistaken as always been part of ECMAScript.

Comment: @Paul: Yes (but that's true _mostly_ in case of CSS/HTML). Also in this case WebKit was verified already. And I've stopped using FF... ;)

Comment: @Mrchief I'm afraid the LCD argument doesn't really work with IE. It's often the case that if something works in IE 7, it's by accident rather than by design.

Comment: @Jared: First, you guys are taking this way too seriously :). Secondly, either way, you care about if it works or not, right? Lastly, webkit was verified in this case. Also, now-a-days, people design for FF/Webkit and then come to IE to see what breaks, so in that regard, I said that.